# Loading Message using Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using Datatables with PHP and Mongo to make a CRUD.

This is my Code and it works fine

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "ajax": "./get_clients"
});
```

This is my function to load new data and it works fine:

```
table.ajax.reload();
```

When I load the page I get a "Loading..." message, but when I reload with "table.ajax.reload()", I get no "Loading..." message which is annoying cause my users might not know the grid is loading.

I can add this line to my datatable params:

```
"processing": true,
```

And that would give me a "Processing..." Message with a different CSS style.

I'd like to know if there is a way to have the "Loading..." message with all of its properties while still using my reload ajax code.

Edit: Im' using version Data tables 1.10.10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really. The "Loading..." message is an actual table row that is added during initialisation, whereas the "Processing..." message is an overlay.

I suggest using the language feature to blank the "Loading..." message and just use the overlay:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax: '/ajax/arrays.txt',
    processing: true,
    'language':{ 
       "loadingRecords": "&nbsp;",
       "processing": "Loading..."
    }
  } );

  $('#reload').click( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
  } );

} );
```

You could of course not use `&nbsp;` and set `loadingRecords` to an empty string, but that initial table row's height will collapse somewhat without.

Example: http://live.datatables.net/cepunoyi/1/edit

Comment: Thank you ! Works perfectly...!