# DataTables loading message not showing when using server side processing

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've read [Loading Message using Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645263/loading-message-using-datatables)

DataTables 1.10.16 using ajax source data and server side mode.

My table has the following initialisation code:

```
var substancesTable = $('#substancesTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "searching": false,

   "ajax": function(data, callback){
       // code for ajax request
   },
   "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ per page",
        "zeroRecords": "Sorry no records found",
        "info": "Showing <b>_START_ to _END_</b> (of _TOTAL_)",
        "infoFiltered": "",
        "infoEmpty": "No records found",
        "processing": '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>'
    },
});
```

DataTables correctly uses the `"processing"` property - it shows a FontAwesome spinner (`.fa-spinner`) when the data is ready to be rendered by DataTables; which happens when the ajax request is complete.

However, I want to show a message - such as "Loading data..." - whilst the ajax request is in process.

So the advice on the previous SO link says about using the `loadingRecords` property within `language`. So I added this:

```
"language:" {
    // ...
    "loadingRecords": "Loading data..."
}
```

This does nothing.

Furthermore, I would prefer to use something similar to my overlay which I set using the `processing` property. I believe that using `loadingRecords` only adds a row to the table whilst the ajax process is being completed, which isn't ideal anyway.

I can't see anything in DataTables documentation about this.

What options do I have here? How do I inform the user that the ajax request is in process? This happens quite a lot as some searches take >4 seconds in my application due to the nature of the data being searched.

There is conflicting (and wrong) information on the DataTables website: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/41654/how-to-display-a-progress-indicator-for-serverside-processing says that `processing` property can be used for this question. But https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.processing (correctly) says that this is for "when the table is processing a user action". 
In my experience `processing` only fires when DataTables is doing some client-side work (i.e. updating the table), nothing to do with waiting for server side data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the `language.loadingRecords` [reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.loadingRecords): (formatted for clarity)

> Note that this parameter is **not used when loading data by
>   server-side processing**, just Ajax sourced data with client-side
>   processing.

So in your case — using server-side processing, the loading message/indicator will never appear.

However, it's actually a simple table row (`tr`) element which DataTables adds to the table body (`tbody`), so you can manually add the `tr` from your `ajax` [option/function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax).

Here's an example where I used [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make the AJAX request, and the `beforeSend` option to display the loading message:

*[Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exLxNG/left/?editors=1010#0)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    language: {
      processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>'
    },
    ajax: function(data, callback){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/path/to/some-file',
        'data': data,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
          // Here, manually add the loading message.
          $('#example > tbody').html(
            '<tr class="odd">' +
              '<td valign="top" colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Loading&hellip;</td>' +
            '</tr>'
          );
        },
        success: function(res){
          callback(res);
        }
      });
    }
  } );
} );
```

And if your `ajax` option is an *object* (which DataTables simply passes to `jQuery.ajax()`), then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    language: {
      processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>'
    },
    ajax: {
      url: 'http://example.com/path/to/some-file',
      beforeSend: function(){
        // Here, manually add the loading message.
        $('#example > tbody').html(
          '<tr class="odd">' +
            '<td valign="top" colspan="6" class="dataTables_empty">Loading&hellip;</td>' +
          '</tr>'
        );
      }
    }
  } );
} );
```

**Note:** Change the `example` to your table ID and the `colspan` value to the appropriate one based on your table..

Comment: This is a really helpful answer thank you for explaining this so well. In my case I had to adapt it a bit as I'm using a custom ajax function to send some form data to an endpoint that performs a complex search. However using `beforeSend:` inside that ajax call and putting in the markup you suggested does exactly what's needed.

Comment: Hey Andy, I'm glad it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set your [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option of DataTables. It has a default value of `lfrtip`. The `r` stands for p**r**ocessing display element. Combine it with the `language.processing` option with your desired value.

Also, I've noticed you're using ajax source data with server side mode on. As detailed on the documentation, the [language.loadingRecords](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.loadingRecords) must only be used if you're initializing by ajax sourced data with client-side processing.

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "dom": 'lrtip',
    "language": {
        "processing": 'Loading data...'
     }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't show "loading data..." at any point.

Answer (score 0):

Just add these lines inside datatable function

```
language: {
  processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i>'
},
```